# Why is Windows.dcu being flagged as a virus?? DELPHI

Tags: windows, delphi, virus

I thought maybe the delphi virus had infected my .dcu so I recompiled windows.pas that was in Delphi's C:\Program Fiels...\source\Win32\rtl\win. Here are the results.

Here's the virustotal result

http://www.virustotal.com/analisis/419f755ae57e6ba469f5c6e36305153dc298517edae2f48ae24af6682335260b-1281224937

I reformated my computer and reinstalled Delphi aswell.
I'm using Delphi 2007.

Comment: This sounds like a question for superuser.com

Comment: From a programmers viewpoint: windows.dcu is a piece of compiled code that seems to be calling a lot of suspicious Windows API functions. It's just not linked to any main code but some anti-virus products just analyze the whole thing and detect lots of suspicious API calls, which results in false positives. (Jeff, does this make it on-topic again? ;-) )

Answer (score 2):

I am not even going to ask why you `thought maybe the delphi virus had infected my .dcu` :-)

Whatever your reason, don't worry too much. I uninstalled and then reinstalled Delphi and uploaded Delphi.dcu to virustotal and got the same result as you - which means that our files are identical (it said that mine had already been analyzed, so I guess it compares MD5 or such).

Bottom line - your windows.dcu is identical with a "fresh out of the box" version and one single virus checker from dozens reports something suspicious. Verdict: false positive. I will sleep well tonight knowing that this file is on my PC.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like only one of those virus scanners is picking it up.  If this is the original dcu from a legitimate copy of Delphi, then you have nothing to worry about.  It's just a false positive.  Try reporting it to McAfee so they can update their definitions.